# Making animate() smooth on $(window).scroll()

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a logo image that animates to 50% size when window is scrolled. My problem is that the animation runs several times while the window scrolls. How can I make it animate once while the window is scrolled > 62px and once again if the window is scrolled back above 62px? I tried adding classes and remove them but without luck. I searched SO but couldn't find a duplicate or similar question (my bad if there is!).

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtheman/kEtPd/ (added some extra css in jsfiddle to simulate my real project)

Relevant HTML:

```
 <body>
   <header>
      <div id="logo">
           <img src="/img/logo.png">
       </div>
 ...
```

CSS:

```
header { position:relative;   }
header #logo { position:absolute; top: 62px; left: 0; width: 365px; height: 53px; }
header #logo img { position:absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 365px; height: 53px; }
```

And my jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    var scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollpos > 62)
    {
        $('#logo img').stop().animate({ 'width': '182px', 'height': '26px'},1000);
    }
    else 
    {
        $('#logo img').stop().animate({ 'width': '365px', 'height': '53px'},200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the width is still original size (`365px`) so that it only animates if the image hasn't already started being resized:

```
if (scrollpos > 62)
{
   if ($('#logo img').width() == 365){
     $('header').css({'position':'fixed','top':'-62px'});
     $('#logo img').stop().animate({ 'width': '182px', 'height': '26px'},1000);
   }
}
```

[**-- SEE WORKING DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/kEtPd/2/)

Comment: Great Curt. I'm implementing the solution now to see if its 100% working. I'll check back soon!

Comment: Yes, working! Thanks. I added a check also on the restore animation just to make that resize work a little smoother also with `if($img.width()<365) { ... ` does it sound like a good idea? (seem to work better!), see http://jsfiddle.net/jtheman/kEtPd/3/ my edit.

Comment: Makes sense :) It'll stop it from restarting the animation if you scroll within the first 62px